# How to Find the first occurrence of the ZZ identity and then store the value in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I want to store the value `'202202171100DF'` Which is coming after the first occurrence of `ZZ`.

```
DECLARE @Element1 VARCHAR(100)='DO#0000000000#ZZ#202202171100DF#ZZ#1#ZZ#20122877GH'
```

Below query will get the all values after the first occurrence of `ZZ`. I just want, it should get the first occurrence of `ZZ`. i.e.`'202202171100DF'`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Element1,CHARINDEX('ZZ',@Element1)+3,len(@Element1));
```

Comment: I, personally, would recommend doing this outside of T-SQL; it's string manipulation abilities is poor at best. Ideally pass the data to SQL Server in a normalised format.

Comment: `CHARINDEX` has a third paramter to tell the DBMS from where to start searching. So look for 'ZZ#', then look for the next '#' after that, thus you get the start and end position (and thus the length) of the substring you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this really isn't a task for T-SQL. It has poor string manipulation functionality. There are a couple of methods you could use, though.

The first is similar to the method you attempted, using `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`:

```sql
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100)='DO#0000000000#ZZ#202202171100DF#ZZ#1#ZZ#20122877GH';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ELEMENT1, CHARINDEX('ZZ#', @ELEMENT1) + 3, CHARINDEX('#', @ELEMENT1 + '#',CHARINDEX('ZZ#', @ELEMENT1) + 3) - (CHARINDEX('ZZ#', @ELEMENT1) + 3));
```

This is pretty messy, with all the references to `CHARINDEX`, but does get the job done.

Another method is the split the string into parts and then return the first row where the "identifier" has the value `'ZZ'`. Unfortunately (hopefully until SQL Server 2022) SQL Server's in-built string splitter, `STRING_SPLIT` doesn't return the ordinal position, so we'll need to use something else such as a JSON splitter. Then you can use a pivot to match the identifier to the value and then get the "first" entry:

```sql
DECLARE @ELEMENT1 VARCHAR(100)='DO#0000000000#ZZ#202202171100DF#ZZ#1#ZZ#20122877GH';

WITH Identities AS(
    SELECT [key] / 2 AS Entry,
           MAX(CASE WHEN [key] % 2 = 0 THEN [Value] END) AS [Identity],
           MAX(CASE WHEN [key] % 2 = 1 THEN [Value] END) AS [Value]
    FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(@ELEMENT1,'#', '","'),'"]')) OJ
    GROUP BY [key] / 2)
SELECT TOP (1)
       [Value]
FROM Identities
WHERE [Identity] = 'ZZ'
ORDER BY Entry ASC;
```

But, again, ideally do this out of T-SQL. If you need to send such data to SQL Server, do so in a normalised format or in properly defined JSON or XML, which SQL Server can natively consume (in all fully supported versions).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu . I agree, with SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX It can get pretty messy but it does the work.    I like the idea of JSON splitter and will use in future implementation.